# Fatal Error When Trying to Set UITextField Placeholder Text programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I created the UITextField from storyboard and it has been connected to the view controller class properly. But when I tried to set its placeholder text using:

```
enTextField.placeholder = "lol"
```

I got this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: How you declare enTextField?

Comment: Like @IBOutlet weak var enTextField: UITextField!

Comment: @girish_pro I did. The problem is I was trying to set its placeholder in wrong place. See Swinny89's answer and my comment. I will accept his answer after the 10min limitation :)

Comment: Fine. It will help other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like the textfield is nil, i'm assuming that you're trying to set this before the view has been properly initialised.

Comment: Wow you are right! I was trying to do this in `didSet` instead of in `viewDidLoad`. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, any time :)

Answer (score 0):

Its happening due to lost the IBOutlet connection. Check your textfield connected or not.